# get another resource

Tags: jsp, jstl, base-url

I have resource on path rest/articles which produces XML. Now I would like to get this resource in page.jsp

I have tried this way :

```
<c:url var="url" value="/rest/articles"/>
<c:import var="data" url="${url}"/>
<c:out value="${data}"/>
```

but exception occurs :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException /project-1.0/rest/articles
```

I might add "http://localhost:8080" prefix in c:import tag `<c:import var="data" url="http://localhost:8080${url}"/>`but I would like not to make this depended.

Is there anyway to handle this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way.

Edited*

```
<%
    public static String getURLWithContextPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
       return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
    }
%>
<c:url var="url" value="${getURLWithContextPath(pageContext.request)}/rest/articles"/>
<c:import var="data" url="${url}"/>
<c:out value="${data}"/>
```

Comment: no, it makes  project-1.0 doubled, like this : `/project-1.0/project-1.0/rest/articles`

Comment: yea, it is working:) I've made it this way :
`<c:set var="prefix" value="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath }"/>`